# Golden Gate ERROR OGG-05263 No GGSCHEMA clause

Tags: oracle12c, oracle-golden-gate

In OTN I am using these instructions to "try" and configure GoldenGate with a MSSQL Source DB to an Oracle12c Target DB
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/datawarehouse/oracle-sqlserver-goldengate-460262.html
Replicating Transactions Between Microsoft SQL Server and Oracle Database Using Oracle GoldenGate

Everything goes okay up till the command:
GGSCI (MSSQL) 2> ADD TRANDATA HRSCHEMA.EMP

Where I get the error:
ERROR   OGG-05263  No GGSCHEMA clause was specified in the GLOBALS file. Please specify a GGSCHEMA shema name.

I searched and saw that currently there was no "GLOBALS" file.   So I created one:
F:\GG\dirprm\globals.prm
And added one line:
GGSCHEMA hrschema

That did not help.
Still getting the same error.

Any suggestions?
Are there GoldenGate Environment variables that I need to have??

Thank-you in advace for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from Oracle Support:
The GLOBALS file should be in the main installation folder. Please remove the same from the dirprm file.
Also the GLOBALS file does not have extension. I could see that you have mentioned it as GLOBALS.prm

Made those changes and it works!